# Power BI Desktop - how do i see custom visuals

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I've made custom visuals on my personal machine in the past but am trying to do the same using a corporate system.

I can see my custom visual at https://app.powerbi.com, but not through Power BI Desktop or on https://localhost:8080. I'm assuming these two are connected. When i run command `pbiviz start` from my CLI, the localhost doesn't launch, either.

I can't sign up for PowerBI web service at work, so I've used a personal account temporarily. I need to view and debug my custom visuals in localhost or within PBI Desktop instead.

I'm using Power BI version 2.46.4732.721 64-bit (May 2017).

My custom visual requires no data - it's the sample visual:

[image: Power BI custom visual basic]

**Power BI Desktop**: When I import the custom visual into PBI Desktop, I see the static placeholder image. I get similar images when I click other graphics, e.g. Donut Chart. These graphics require data to show anything. But even if I try adding data to the custom visual, it just shows the placeholder. (No data is required in the web service version of PBI - the image just shows straight away.)

[image: Custom visual static placeholder image]

**Localhost**: The error I'm getting in IE11 & FF52 is from line 37 of visual.ts: this.target=options.element. "Unable to get property element of undefined". But surely the same variable is used in app.powerbi.com, where it's working fine. I get this line: `plugin myTestVisualDC00AEEDDF6D475989B6E1D88E1A21DF_DEBUG`.

[image: Debug IE11 of localhost:8080]

I've already followed the debugging instructions about trusting certificates and enabling developer visuals within app.powerbi.com.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for any help
Emma

Comment: app.powerbi.com is the only way to debug custom visuals. What's the problem with using personal account?

Comment: Did you package your new visual (pbiviz package) before you imported to Desktop?

Comment: @ Foxan Ng - Is it normal to see only the static placeholder image in Power BI Desktop? Do I have to publish the report to the web in order to see the image? Thanks

Comment: @Marc Pincince - Yes, I packaged it into a .pbiviz file and it imported successfully. Thanks

Comment: Note that when using the *Debug visual*, your visual code initiates immediately. But for typical visuals, it is normal to see just the watermark before data fields are populated - do you still see the watermark after connecting data to the visual?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging Power BI Custom Visuals with PBI Desktop, you follow these instructions (for Windows).

1. Setup Windows Settings to allow **Developer mode** and **Device Portal** functionality
2. Open command-line window
3. Set following environment variable:

   `set WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS=--enable-features=msEdgeDevToolsWdpRemoteDebugging`
4. Run pbidesktop.exe in it's installation folder (for example in *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin*)
5. Open Microsoft Edge browser and type `edge://inspect`
6. In the process which ends with `/ReportView.htm` select **inspect**
7. You can see now the normal debugging tools in Developer Tools window and running Custom Visuals

Please look this link for more detailed description.
https://medium.com/@mikko.lahdeaho_45453/tackling-obstacles-in-power-bi-custom-visual-development-9f3572bd4f19

-Mikko